# Is it possible to put "delete" in comma expression

Tags: c++, c, comma-operator

I would like to return some material in the struct referenced by a pointer and then delete the struct.

In Java, just return the value and the garbage collection system will delete the struct automatically.

But in C++, the way I can imagine is not very clean, that using a temporary variable to store the things for return, deleting the pointer and then returning the value stored.

I try another tricky way using comma expression as "`return ptr->value, delete ptr`", but there is a compile error says "void value not ignored as it ought to be".

Is there any possible way to achieve that more elegantly?

Thanks a lot.

---

Updated

Thanks a lot for suggestions from everybody. In fact the original motivation of my problem is about the comma expression which I would like to use for some shorter code. And I found the discussion is more about the usage of pointers in C++. It's also another very interesting topic.

I have used C for years so I am more familiar with raw pointer and have little experience with smart pointer. At my first thought, there are two basic conditions where we need pointers. One is reference to a large piece of memory allocated in heap and the other is for dynamically allocation such as link list node or tree node(eg. my original problem came out while writing a BST-like struct).

So in C++ programming, is smart pointer the best choice for both cases? If we consider the efficiency, such as working on some low level library, is it possible to encapsulate the raw pointer inside the class completely for less memory leak risk?

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Don't use pointers, and if you must, use smart pointers (`std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr`).

In your case, it could be as simple as

```
//...
return obj.value;  //no pointer needed
                   //automatic memory management
```

or

```
//...
return smartPtr->value;  //smart pointer automatically cleans up after itself
```

You probably can't imagine the *clean* way of doing it in C++ because C++ is taught as C, with pointers and memory management issues. Proper C++ uses **RAII** and doesn't suffer from that.

Answer (score 2):

No, in your case, because the function is supposed to return some value, but comma operator evaluates to the right most operand, which in your case is `delete` expression, which is just `void`.

Answer (score 2):

The usual solution is, first, to not use pointers, so that there
is nothing to delete, and second, when there are other resources
to be cleaned up, to do the cleanup in a destructor, which will
automatically be called *after* the return statement has copied
the return value to where ever it has to copy it.

If you can return it, you can copy it, so it shouldn't be
allocated dynamically,  The most notable exception is where
polymorphic objects are involved; polymorphism requires pointers
or references to work, and most of the time (although there are
exceptions), the polymorphic object will be dynamicallly
allocated.  In this case, if the actual lifetime of the
polymorphic object corresponds to local scope, you can use
`std::auto_ptr` (or `std::unique_ptr` in the unlikely case that
you can count on C++11).

Answer (score 1):

If you dynamically allocate a pointer inside a function. what you can do is:

consider you want to return an `int` variable

```
int foo()
{
  MyStruct *obj;

  obj=new MyStruct;

  .....

  int x=obj->value;

  delete obj;

  return x;
}
```

Or you can also do:

```
int foo()
{
  MyStruct obj;

  obj=new MyStruct;

  .....

  return obj.value;
}
```

this way you won't have to worry about memory leaks..
This is the easiest method. Sure you can use smart pointers. But at your level I would say stick with this method.

Comment: What's wrong with `MyStruct obj; return obj.value;`? You think this is good advice to give to a beginner?

Comment: The syntax is correct.  The problem is that the type and the return value of the comma operator are those of the second expression.  And the `delete` expression has a type `void` and no return value, so it cannot be used as the last element of a comma operator in a `return` statement, at least if there is a return value.

Comment: So what happens with the first expression `ptr->value`? is it returned or what?

Comment: @alfred no it is discarded by the comma operator. but if the function returns void, such a return statement is entirely correct.

Comment: so the last expression decides the fate of the return in comma case that is wether it will be successful or will end up with error